# How to deal with default padding and margins

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I am fairly comfortable with html5/css3 now, so I am trying to make a site using same and make it responsive.

So far things are going smoothly except for these two problems:

1. the use of **em** i dont understand the calculations at all, especially why i have to put this **font: .81em/150%** i am following a guide from a tutorial online.
2. i am having some imaginary padding on my div, you can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/NhZ2A/

e.g. I have on the body:

```
 body{padding:0px; margin:0px;}
```

Then I have a div with an image like this:

```
 <div id="slider">
     <img src="images/slider.jpg"/>
 </div>
```

Then in my css I have:

```
 #slider{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

 #slider img{
   width:60%;
   height:auto;
}
```

With the above css I still have padding on the slider div below or maybe it's a margin on the image below.

I don't understand why and its killing me.

Comment: well 1em=16px same for 100%. use this tool if need arise http://pxtoem.com/

Comment: I don't understand why everyone is giving reset CSS solutions for this question, OP could use them but they are not an answer to his questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second issue :

The space is not padding, it is created because the `<img>` tag is an inline element and therefore has a `whitespace` use `display:block;` on the `<img>` tag to remove it.

Comment: display:block solved that problem, thanks man...will accept your answer if i cant find anybody to explain how to calculate em

Comment: @user2666633 I was thinking about the font issue, but I don't realy understand your issue could you explain please?

Comment: i am trying to design a responsive website and i read it is advisable to use em instead of px, but there is this weird calculations where you set body font to 100% then for fonts in other containers your dive px by 100% to get the correct em value, its confusing

Comment: @user2666633 well, I still don't see what you mean, sorry :( The only advise I can give is to take a look at this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size

Answer (score 1):

Use css resets , To get consistent cross-browser experience,it should be included,any one among these.

Eric Meyer’s Reset CSS

HTML5 Doctor CSS Reset

Yahoo! (YUI 3) Reset CSS

Normalize.css

Get it from here --> http://www.cssreset.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, CSS reset is important to set default initial value for each element.

**reset.css** Source - [**Reset5**](http://code.google.com/p/reset5/)

```
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,audio,canvas,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,mark,menu,meter,nav,output,progress,section,summary,time,video
{
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
    body
{
    line-height:1
}
    article,aside,dialog,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section,blockquote
{
    display:block
}
    nav ul
{
    list-style:none
}
    ol
{
    list-style:decimal
}
    ul
{
    list-style:disc
}
    ul ul
{
    list-style:circle
}
    blockquote,q
{
    quotes:none
}
    blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after
{
    content:none
}
    ins
{
    text-decoration:underline
}
    del
{
    text-decoration:line-through
}
    mark
{
    background:none
}
    abbr[title],dfn[title]
{
    border-bottom:1px dotted #000;
    cursor:help
}
    table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0
}
    hr
{
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0
}
    input[type=submit],input[type=button],button
{
    margin:0!important;
    padding:0!important
}
    input,select,a img
{
    vertical-align:middle
}
```

---

**em** - Unit measurement values (1em is equal to the current font-size,same as 2em = 2*font-size)

**Font Syntax:**

```
font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family;
```

In your question value **.81em/150%**

**.81em/150%** - **font-size/line-height**

Answer (score 0):

Every browser has a default behaviour and configuration

If you want a clean start from all of them, you must set it with a "reset.css" style sheet, to avoid undesirable behaviours and have all homogeneous.

Check this SO answer to get a proper reset CSS stylesheet:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167531/best-practice-for-css-reset-style-sheet

Answer (score 0):

The first choice will be

## Css Resets

## [Most Used Css Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 0):

JUSR USE CSS RESET

```
* { 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
 }
```